# Zeppelin connecting to DSE Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to connect Zeppelin to DSE Analytics. Assuming that I'm using Docker for this test. I have tried some things:

1 - I've tried to use the Zeppelin image and connect to Spark Master on DSE container.

2 - I've created a docker image with a custom zeppelin DSE that connect to DSE Spark Cluster.

Is there any way to connect Zeppelin to DSE Analytics Cluster?

I know that Apache Livy can solve this question, but I have some limits to use it.

`version: '3'
services:
  dse:
    image: "datastax/dse-server:6.0.1"
    command: -k
    environment: 
      DS_LICENSE: accept
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "5598:5598"
      - "8090:8090"
      - "7077:7077"
      - "7080:7080"
    volumes: 
      - "C:/zeppelin-dse/dse-fs:/var/lib/dsefs"
  zeppelin:
    image: "apache/zeppelin:0.8.0"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "C:/zeppelin/logs:/logs"
      - "C:/zeppelin/notebook:/notebook"
    links: 
      - "dse"`

[zeppelin configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psSbu.png)

Comment: Can you show how you start Docker for both DSE & Zeppelin? What ports, etc. are exposed?

Comment: Zeppelin can work with DSE, you only need to provide correct configuration & have ports open. Can you answer my question above?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Hmmm, and how are you specifying the Spark master? and other configuration parameters inside Zeppelin?

Comment: I added the zeppelin configuration to the question. In summary, I edited master to `spark://dse:7077` and added `SPARK_HOME`